# Wordpress pagination URL posts not load

Tags: pagination, urls, get-posts

I set up wordpress newly and add next previous pagination in home page using following code

```
next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0);
previous_posts_link('« Newer Entries', 0);
```

Pagination URL work correct. when click previous link it go to http:www.mydomain.com/blog/page/2/ URL but content not load. IT shows same first page blog post list. I have 70 blog posts and each page show 4 post. How do I load post in pagination URL? Do I need to make any .htaccess or WP setting change?

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 4);
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
$a = get_post_custom();
    $blogroll_image = $a['mainImage'];
    print('
    <section class="main_post bg_white fl">
        <section class="post_img fl">');
    print('<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="'.$blogroll_image[0].'" width="385" height="385" alt=""/></a>'); 
    print('</section>
        <section class="post_content fl col_light_blue">
        <p>' . get_the_date() .' </p>');
        the_title('<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h1 class="col_light_blue">', '</h1></a>'); 
    print(the_excerpt('<p>', '</p>'));
    print('</section>   
    <!-- end .main_post -->
    </section>
    <div class="spacer_1px"></div>');   
endforeach;
        next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0);
        previous_posts_link('« Newer Entries', 0);
```

Comment: are you calling `query_posts` or otherwise altering the query  in your template?

Comment: Yes I am calling `query_posts`

Comment: Could you paste your code, do you have it on the index.php or another page template?

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/4771) and [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/4771). don't use `query_posts` to alter the main query. post the query code you are using in your template if you need help fixing it.

Comment: @jepser I have it on index.php I will put code in top

Comment: @Milo I have update code with `get_posts()` . but now every post in the shows same title. my code in the top.

Comment: it's not clear why you're using query_posts or get_posts at all, WordPress does the main query for you before loading the template. if you simply want to change posts_per_page to something other than your site-wide settings, use pre_get_posts.

Comment: @Milo as an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using query_posts or get_posts at all, WordPress does the main query for you before loading the template. If you simply want to change posts_per_page to something other than your site-wide settings, use pre_get_posts.